# Geokit returning results in English vs other languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, geokit

I just tried to geocode the simple address 'Tokyo' using Geokit 1.6.0 and the geocoder returned 東京都 instead of 'Tokyo'.

How can I ask that the Geocoder always return results in English?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/imajes/geokit? Could you post sample code? What does Geokit::Geocoder.provider_order return?

Answer (score 1):

Geokit doesn't allow you to specify a language option (even if the provider you're using can take it). If you're using Google for your provider you can at minimum override the `do_geocode` method to accept a language option (example [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/geokit/language/geokit/WyS0xoH2jb4/oSJinHCEUHgJ)).

Alternatively, I suggest using the [Geocoder gem](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/):

```
$ gem install geocoder
$ geocode 'Tokyo'
Latitude:         35.6894875
Longitude:        139.6917064
Full address:     Tokyo, Japan
City:             
State/province:   Tokyo
Postal code:      
Country:          Japan
Google map:       http://maps.google.com/maps?q=35.6894875,139.6917064
```

By default the Geocoder gem uses Google's geocoding API and the default language is English. But Geocoder takes a language option. Let's try Russian:

```
$ geocode -l ru 'Tokyo'
Latitude:         35.6894875
Longitude:        139.6917064
Full address:     Токио, Япония
City:             
State/province:   Токио
Postal code:      
Country:          Япония
Google map:       http://maps.google.com/maps?q=35.6894875,139.6917064
```

Here's [a list of the languages and language codes](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=p9pdwsai2hDMsLkXsoM05KQ&gid=1) Google's geocoding API supports.